# ¿como puedo hacer una llamada a un WebService SOAP con PHP para descargar ficheros excel de un area documental?

Tags: php, xml, soap, ftp

necesito acceder al area documental de un web service para descargar unos ficheros excel y dejarlos en una ruta concreta de mi equipo para luego poder tratarlo desde mi programa.

El web service tiene un FTP donde los proveedores acceden y dejan sus ficheros en Excel que posteriormente yo necesito descargarme.

Este es el XML que utilizo para descargar cada fichero concreto:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:att="http://attachments.webservice.common.host.bs.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <att:GetFileRequestMsg>
         <fileId>98765</fileId>
         <fileName>Facturacion.xlsx</fileName>     
      </att:GetFileRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

La llamada tengo claro como hacerla, utilizo curl_init(); y curl_setopt desde un fichero PHP.

Lo que necesito exactamente es saber como configurar esa llamada desde el PHP para poder dejar ese fichero excel que me devuelve en una ruta concreta de mi equipo.

La llamada a la WSDL la hago así:

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL,$sUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml2);
    $sOutput2 = curl_exec($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);
```

donde $Url es la WSDL y $xml2 es el XML.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Pues depende mucho de como sea el sitio web. Explicalo

Comment: Hola, pues es no tengo claro exactamente que necesitas saber, yo hago estas llamadas a una wsdl https://......?wsdl, en este caso llamando al método GetFileRequestMsg que es el que devuelve el fichero excel que le solicitamos... Modifico la pregunta para poner como hago la llamada

Comment: Ok, esta llamada, te devuelve otro XML y nunca un excel. Otra cosa es que trates estos datos y los conviertas a excel

Comment: Correcto, ese está preparado para otras llamadas que hago que si que devuelven un XML, pero en este caso que me devolvería un XLS, ¿como debería hacerlo? y ¿como guardar ese fichero en una ruta concreta de mi equipo?

Comment: yo conozoco ningun service SOAP que no te devuelva otra cosa que no sea un XML, sinceramente. Si ocurre como te digo, lo que haces es tratar el XML, convertirlo en XLS y descargarlo en el ordenador que hizo la peticion. Como se descarga? al crear el fichero pones la cabeceras tipicas de php  
                `// header('Content-Type: application/zip');
  // header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $download");
  // header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download));
  // header("Location: $download");`